# Adding int's together and getting the wrong anser

Tags: python, int, calculation

I am writing a casino dice game which asks the user to enter a wager and a dice number. The result of the dice number will either deduct the wager from the balance or add the wager * 6 to the balance. When the user guesses incorrectly, the correct value is deducted from the balance.

with a remaining balance of 490 and upon winning with bet after making a wager of 5 the new balance is 556045. This should obviously be 520.

Why would the new balance be 556045?

My code is below along with the output

```
    import random

print("Welcome to the casino")
UserName = input("Please enter your name: ")
print("Thanks for playing " + UserName + "! We wish you the best of luck!")

balanceRemaining = 500
while balanceRemaining != 0:
    RandomNumber = random.randint(1, 6)
    Wager = input("Please enter a wager: ")
    UserNumber = input("Enter a number: ")
    print("Dice number was " + str(RandomNumber))
    if int(UserNumber) != RandomNumber:
        balanceRemaining = balanceRemaining - int(Wager)
        print("Your Balance is now: " + str(balanceRemaining))
    else:
        Winnings = int(Wager * 6)
        balanceRemaining = int(Winnings) + int(balanceRemaining)
        print("Your Balance is now: " + str(balanceRemaining))
```

Output

```
Please enter a wager: 5
Enter a number: 5
Dice number was 1
Your Balance is now: 495
Please enter a wager: 5
Enter a number: 5
Dice number was 6
Your Balance is now: 490
Please enter a wager: 5
Enter a number: 5
Dice number was 5
Your Balance is now: 556045
```

Comment: `Winnings = int(Wager * 6)` you meant `Winnings = int(Wager) * 6`

Comment: Those damn brackets! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the wager string **before** multiplying:

```
Winnings = int(Wager) * 6
```

`Wager` is a string, so `'5'`, and multiplying strings is allowed, that produces a new string with the value repeated:

```
>>> '5' * 6
'555555'
```

Converting that new string then, produces a much larger winning than you intended.

It's best to convert user input *early*, so it is harder to make mistakes like these elsewhere in your code. This also helps reduce the number of places you need to convert that input to integers:

```
Wager = int(input("Please enter a wager: "))
UserNumber = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's actually interesting. Here you input a string:

```
Wager = input("Please enter a wager: ")
```

And `Wager` is, in your case, the *string* `"5"`. Then, you're multiplying this *string* by 6:

```
Winnings = int(Wager * 6)
```

Which is the same as `Winnings = int("5"* 6)`, but `"5"* 6 == '555555'`! Then, `int` converts this to an integer, and you get this incorrect result.

What do you want to convert to an integer: the string `"5"* 6` or the string `"5"`? You most certainly meant:

```
Winnings = int(Wager) * 6
```

Comment: Your correct, I was meant to convert the Wager to a string and multiply by 6. oh the embarrassment!